# Ошибка с condition variable. c++

Tags: c++

Не работает этот код:

```
cond_var[myID].wait(unique_lock<mutex>(mtx[myID]));
```

Объявление переменных таково:

```
condition_variable cond_var[32];
mutex mtx[32];
```

Что говорит MVS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у `std::condition_variable::wait_for` [либо два, либо три параметра](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for).

Во-вторых, первый параметр `std::condition_variable::wait_for` - lvalue-ссылка. Ее нельзя привязать к временному объекту.

Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.

Что вы хотели сказать, передавая туда один аргумент?

Comment: Чтобы программа не кушала ресурсы процессора, пока следующий поток не завершит работу

Comment: Увидел этот код на просторах интернета. В видео он работал, процессор не нагружался.

Comment: @Alleksh_ В передачу временного объекта по ссылке я еще поверить могу - расширение MSVC, но вот в то, что двухпараметрная функция компилировалась с одним аргументом - нет. Вы что-то путаете.

Comment: timecode 4:16  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dth5HkonCYk&list=PLR4wcBxrUGPDNamYfO2JIPKkzrJTyxrhr&index=5

Comment: с wait та же ситуауция

Comment: @Alleksh _: В этом видео, мягко выражаясь, написан "гамнокод". Почему он не компилируется в С++ (и почему он "компилируется" у автора видео) - я уже писал выше.

Comment: @AnT, благодарю за пояснение. Но это не отменило моей проблемы, как обойти busy-waiting?